# Generate Unorderlist list with attributes by recursion

Tags: perl, recursion, nested-lists

I have to generate a data hash such that, the sequence of the node associated is displayed right next to the node name in an unorderedlist

```
my $hash =({
        node_hash =>{
                'Level1' =>{
                              'Level2a' =>{
                                            'Level3a' => 1,
                                            'Level3b' => 1,
                                           }
                              'Level2b' => {
                                              'Level3c' => 1,
                                            'Level3d' => 1,
                                           }

                              }

                      }
        'sequence' => {
                '10' =>{
                              '10.1' =>{
                                            '10.1.1' => 1,
                                            '10.1.1' => 1,
                                           }
                              '10.2' => {
                                            '10.2.1' => 1,
                                            '10.2.2' => 1,
                                           }

                              }

                      } 
                  });
```

Is it possible to associate them such that : the unordered list has the result:

```
<ul>
    <li sequence="10">Level1
                       <ul>
                              <li sequence="10.1">Level2a
                                      <ul>
                                            <li sequence ="10.1.1">Level3a</li>
                                            <li sequence ="10.1.2">Level3b</li>
                                      </ul>
                              </li>
                              <li sequence="10.2">Level2b
                                      <ul>
                                            <li sequence ="10.2.1">Level3c</li>
                                            <li sequence ="10.2.2">Level3d</li>
                                      </ul>
                              </li>
                        </ul>
            </li>
</ul>
```

Right now I am sending the hash to a recursive sub routine and i can generate the list of fields, without the sequence attribute by :

```
unorder($hash->{node_hash});

sub unorder {
my ( $data, $level ) = ( @_, 0 );
my $tab    = '  ';
my $indent = $tab x $level;

print "$indent<ul>\n";
while ( my ( $key, $val ) = each %$data ) {
    print "$indent$tab<li level='".$level."'><a href='#'>$key</a>\n";
    make_ul( $val, $level + 1 ) if ref $val eq 'HASH';
    print "$indent</li>\n";
}
print "$indent</ul>\n";
} ## end sub unorder
```

Comment: Why does `10.1.1` correspond to `Level3a` and `10.2.2` correspond to `Level3d`? Is the mapping arbitrary or do you want to pair elements based on some kind of sorted order?

Comment: Well id you look at both the node_hash and sequence, you will see that 10.1.1 is at the same level as Level3a . 10.1.1 is the child of the 1st node of the 1st node of node_hash and so on

Comment: Yes, I see they're at the same level. But how do you know that `10.1.1` corresponds to `Level3a` and not to `Level3b`, for example?

Answer (score 0):

This gives you sort of what you want:

```
sub unordlist {
    my $first = shift;
    my $second = shift;
    return '' unless ref $first eq "HASH";
    my @a = keys %$first;
    my @b = keys %$second;
    my $return = "<ul>";

    while (my $x = shift @a) {
        my $y = shift @b or die "keys are unbalanced";
        $return .= qq{<li sequence="$y">$x};
        $return .= unordlist ($first->{$x}, $second->{$y});
        $return .= "</li>";
    }
    $return .= "</ul>";

    $return;
}

unordlist ($hash->{ node_hash }, $hash->{ sequence });
```

I will leave the formatting and rational variable names up to you.

Comment: Sorry, I guess the ordering here wont work properly. It won't necessarily associate the correct level with the correct node ... oops.

Comment: @thissuitisblack's point is important. There isn't really a good way to associate the nodes with the levels.

Comment: Sort::Naturally may (or may not) help

Comment: Any sort is bad. The only thing that would appear to work here is the original order, but I don't know way to preserve that. Make the hashes into arrays and it would work.

Comment: right, but from the given example data, it may happen to do the right thing

Comment: I really think this is indicative of problems in the original data structure.